# Cross-Platform Android Studio Project Sync using GitHub

Tags: git, android-studio

I am trying to get my Android Studio project synced between my Windows 7 machine and my Mac running OS X 10.10 through GitHub, such that I'll be able to edit code on both machines. I've been using the VCS tool that AS provides.

I'm running into problems as I import the code from VCS into Android Studio from my GitHub repo - things just aren't resolving and there are errors everywhere.

Are there any considerations to be taken into account as I sync files from Windows to Android Studio on the Mac? Are there any other "gotchas"?

Comment: It's hard to say without more information, but I would guess that you've added things to the .gitignore file that are needed, and/or you have libraries outside of the project folder that are being left out from git entirely.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't check in any files from the .idea directory. Just check in your build.gradle files. Then, when you open it on the other machine, Android Studio will automatically download all the dependencies, and everything should resolve.